# Recursion. The maximum element of each tree branch

Tags: php, recursion

I have a class that builds a recursive menu tree. The choice of data comes from a database where the following fields: `id`, `title`, `id_parent`.

```
class Menu {

private $db;
private $menus_arr = [];

public function __construct() 
{
    $this->db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=test', 'root', 'admin');
    $this->menus_arr = $this->getMenus();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($this->menus_arr);
    echo "</pre>";
}

private function getMenus() 
{
    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM menu");
    $query->execute();
    $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // делаем из одномерного массива двумерный, в котором первый ключ - id_parent
    $arr = [];
    foreach ($result as $value) {
        $arr[$value['id_parent']][] = $value;
    }
    return $arr;
}

public function makeTree($id_parent = 0, $lvl = 0) 
{

    if (isset($this->menus_arr[$id_parent])) { 
        foreach ($this->menus_arr[$id_parent] as $value) {
            echo "<div class='test' style='margin: 5px 0 5px " . ($lvl * 30) . "px;'>$lvl - " . $value['title'] . "</div>"; 
            $lvl++;
            $this->makeTree($value['id'], $lvl); 
            $lvl--; 
        }
    }
}
```

}

I call the method makeTree

```
$tree = new Menu();
$tree->makeTree();
```

Table structure:

[image: table]

Printed recursion tree:

[image: tree]

How can you determine the last element of each branch?

Comment: Is this assignment or practical test ?

Comment: It has no children?

Comment: I need to solve this problem

Comment: yes, the selected elements do not have children

Comment: So you need to do this in php alone? Another question, why would (for example) `"sub menu 2"` not count as a leaf node? It also has no children.

Comment: I believe **makeTree** function finds the descendent nodes of a prent node, right ?

If so, `if (isset($this->menus_arr[$id_parent])) { ` should return false for those who don't have children. And from there, you should be able to work your way up to the most parent element.

Comment: Before that, I did not write correctly) I need to highlight not the elements where there are no children, but those elements that are located below all in the tree.

Comment: So you want the items at *max-depth* in a branch where the root has `id_parent === 0` ? And in php alone?

Comment: Yoshi, yes, where the root has id_parent === 0

Comment: okay, if an elements doesn't have any children, isn't it located at the most deep level ?

Comment: If the neighboring element has children, then this is not the deepest place in the branch

Comment: I'm still not quite sure. Suppose the last element in the list would be: `menu 2 / sub menu 3 / sub menu 3.1 / sub menu 3.1.1`. Should then `menu 2 / sub menu 1 / sub menu 1.1|2` still count as the relevant child nodes?

Comment: Do it simple, when you add new element to tree amrk it as leaf and parent element as branch, so you will know wht is it by that flag

Comment: Yoshi, Yes, this element (menu 2 / sub menu 1 / sub menu 1.1|2) is the last one in the tree, for example, they should be highlighted in red. http://storage6.static.itmages.com/i/18/0131/h_1517393444_3203515_2490f27622.jpeg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After what you wrote in the comments, this is by best guess at the moment:

```
<?php
class Menu
{
    private $menus_arr = [];

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->menus_arr = $this->getMenus();
    }

    private function getMenus()
    {
        // substitute db access
        $result = [
            ['id' =>  1, 'title' => 'm: 1',            'id_parent' =>  0],
            ['id' =>  2, 'title' => 'm: 1.1',          'id_parent' =>  1],
            ['id' =>  3, 'title' => 'm: 1.1.1',        'id_parent' =>  2],
            ['id' =>  4, 'title' => 'm: 1.1.1.1',      'id_parent' =>  3],
            ['id' =>  5, 'title' => 'm: 1.1.1.2',      'id_parent' =>  3],
            ['id' =>  6, 'title' => 'm: 1.1.2',        'id_parent' =>  2],
            ['id' =>  7, 'title' => 'm: 1.1.3',        'id_parent' =>  2],
            ['id' => 19, 'title' => 'm: 1.1.3.1',      'id_parent' =>  7],
            ['id' => 20, 'title' => 'm: 1.1.3.1.1',    'id_parent' => 19],
            ['id' =>  8, 'title' => 'm: 1.2',          'id_parent' =>  1],
            ['id' =>  9, 'title' => 'm: 1.3',          'id_parent' =>  1],
            ['id' => 10, 'title' => 'm: 2',            'id_parent' =>  0],
            ['id' => 11, 'title' => 'm: 2.1',          'id_parent' => 10],
            ['id' => 12, 'title' => 'm: 2.1.1',        'id_parent' => 11],
            ['id' => 13, 'title' => 'm: 2.1.1.1',      'id_parent' => 12],
            ['id' => 14, 'title' => 'm: 2.1.2',        'id_parent' => 11],
            ['id' => 15, 'title' => 'm: 2.2',          'id_parent' => 10],
            ['id' => 16, 'title' => 'm: 2.3',          'id_parent' => 10],
            ['id' => 17, 'title' => 'm: 2.3.1',        'id_parent' => 16],
            ['id' => 18, 'title' => 'm: 2.3.1.1',      'id_parent' => 17],
        ];

        $arr = [];
        foreach ($result as $value) {
            $arr[$value['id_parent']][] = $value;
        }

        return $arr;
    }

    public function makeTree()
    {
        foreach ($this->menus_arr[0] as $root) {
            $this->renderNode($root, 0, $this->getMaxDepth($root));
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param array $node
     * @param int   $depth
     * @param int   $maxDepth
     */
    private function renderNode(array $node, $depth = 0, $maxDepth = 0)
    {
        printf(
            '<div class="test" style="margin: 5px 0 5px %dpx">%s - %s%s</div>',
            $depth * 30,
            $depth,
            $node['title'],
            $depth === $maxDepth ? '&lt;--' : ''
        );

        if (isset($this->menus_arr[$node['id']])) {
            foreach ($this->menus_arr[$node['id']] as $child) {
                $this->renderNode($child, $depth + 1, $maxDepth);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param array $root
     *
     * @return int
     */
    private function getMaxDepth(array $root)
    {
        $result = 0;

        if (isset($this->menus_arr[$root['id']])) {
            foreach ($this->menus_arr[$root['id']] as $child) {
                $result = max($result, $this->getMaxDepth($child) + 1);
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}

$tree = new Menu();
$tree->makeTree();
```

Comment: Thank you, Yoshi. That's exactly what I wanted to do.

Comment: Although, not quite right. Added to your array  ['id' => 19, 'title' => 'm: 1.1.3.1','id_parent' => 7], ['id' => 20, 'title' => 'm: 1.1.3.1.1', 'id_parent' => 19].  http://storage7.static.itmages.com/i/18/0131/h_1517401126_4391988_10ce17f203.jpeg

Comment: @user381403 I changed my answer. It now calculates the max depth for a given root so that it can be used while displaying a node.

Comment: Thank you, Yoshi.

Answer (score -1):

We can achieve through SQL. we should use window function to determine the last element of tree.

Comment: I need to do through the makeTree() method